# Returning error codes from a C function which returns object pointer?

Tags: c

This is the signature of my object create function:

`struct object *object_create();`

If the object is successfully created it it returns pointer to the object, and `0` otherwise.

How would I return some error codes from the same function? I need about ten codes.

I suppose mixing error codes and object pointer is not the way to go?

Comment: Folks round here often frown upon global variables, but something like that (along the lines of the standard `errno` variable) would work. Or you can add a parameter to your function - `int* errorcode`.

Comment: How specific do you need it to be? `errno` is the only standard way, but that's limited to 3 error flags unless you define your own.

Comment: Is it an opaque struct or one with internals exposed? What other errors than failing to allocate can occur? It the function part of a larger lib with some library standard error type?

Comment: As for the answer to the question "Should I ever use errno for error handling", the answer is probably "Err... no." :) Global error result variables were always a steady source of bugs.

Comment: The object internals are not exposed. Several errors need to be returned, about ten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are pretty much only two acceptable options:

1. `struct object *object_create (myerr_t* result, /* ... */);`
   Return the struct and pass the function result as parameter.
2. `myerr_t object_create (struct object** obj, /* ... */);`
   Return the function result and pass a pointer to the struct by parameter.

**Pros of 1:**

- It has the advantage that you can assign variables directly on the caller side:
  `struct object* obj = object_create(/* ... */);`
- Pointer-to-pointer interfaces add a slight bit of complexity which can be avoided this way.

**Pros of 2:**

- Reserving the return value of a function for an error code is an industry "de facto" standard way of designing APIs/libs. It is common to to use the same result type for the whole lib and have every function return it.
- You have the option not to modify the struct in case of errors, leaving the caller's variable intact. Mainly matters in case of "realloc-like" interfaces.

---

I would not advise anyone to use `errno` because using a global error result variable is obscure, error prone, severely restricted and (pre-C11) not thread-safe. Also it might conflict with skunky, legacy error handling by various standard/POSIX lib functions.

I would not advise to use any wrapper hacks either, such as wrapping the returned struct in a larger one or over-allocating an error code at the end. This just adds complexity and potential for bugs.

An error handler should be *simple*, not introduce potential errors of its own due to added complexity! Anything else but a plain enum result code is questionable practice.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple options:

1. Set [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/errno).
2. Change the function signature to either of these:

   1. `int object_create(struct object **ret);`
   2. `struct object *object_create(int *err);`
3. Declare and use your own `errno` equivalent (care needs to be taken to make this work safely with threads, i.e. you probably want a thread-local variable).
4. Create a structure that can hold your object as well as an error code; either `struct object` itself, or some wrapper. This option isn’t as common in C since it works best with generic types (e.g. C++, where you could create a generic `Result<T, Err>` type).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is advisable (in fact, I am pretty sure it is not), but I have seen people doing things like (ok, I admit, I am the one doing it. I am not always doing advisable things).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

# define ONE (struct object *)1

// Example structure
struct object {
    char *name;
};

struct object *object_create(){
    struct object *ret=(struct object *)malloc(sizeof(struct object));
    if(!ret) return NULL;
    ret->name = malloc(80);
    if(!ret->name){
        free(ret);
        return ONE;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    struct object *myobj=object_create();
    if(myobj==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot create object\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(myobj==ONE){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate memory for name\n");
        return 2;
    }
    // start playing with myobj
    sprintf(myobj->name, "Hello");
}
```

Argument is because of alignment, and because of pragmatism knowledge of how segments works, malloc could never return 1.

You could even double ensure that, my mallocing memory just for your sort of `enum`.

```c
void initEnum(struct object *code1, struct object *code2, struct object *code3){
    struct object *ret=(struct object *)malloc(3);
    code1=ret;
    code2=(struct object *)(1+(char *)ret);
    code3=(struct object *)(2+(char *)ret);
}
```

And then, use `code1`, `code2`, `code3` as special meaning values for your object. (Note that there is no memory allocated for those object. Just a few bytes by `malloc(3)`, that makes sure that no object can share those addresses).
So, it is a little bit like `NULL`: an address that points to nowhere, and whose only purpose is to be known to points to no legit object, and therefore to be usable for this king a special meaning (NULL is just `(struct object*)0`).

Comment: Some systems might trap if assigning an invalid and/or misaligned value to a pointer. So this might crash at the point where you assign the pointer. So overall, this is a bad idea that creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @Lundin Really? Assigning pointers? I mean, nobody is trying to dereference them. We are just handling values of addresses here. I am just curious. I am not denying that it might be a bad idea. But I have hard time imagining a system monitoring what I put in my variables. Maybe for alignment, indeed (but for that, just allocate 1 int per 'enum' value. Still not costly), if a system has special registers for aligned addresses. But for the rest. Do you have an example of such a system?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the MIPS ISA is such a system. In case this is monitored, it happens at the CPU/MMU level.

Comment: @Lundin So is this for alignment problems? Or segmentation problem? What if we allocated a single byte for each enum value? Or a single `intmax_t`:  `code1=malloc(sizeof(intmax_t));...` Those are legit addresses, well aligned. The only problem is that it would provoke a segfault to try to access them. But it can't be illegal to hold a pointer to a not properly allocated address. I mean, that would make many simple iterations fail such as `for(p=arr, i=0; i<n; i++,p++)` ends up with `p=arr+n`, and is legit even if `arr` is an array of `n` `struct object`.  Or what happens once address is freed?

Comment: The C standard (C17 6.3.2.3 §5) is very clear: "An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
type, and might be a trap representation." Similarly for pointer-to-pointer conversions (§7): "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined." Both cases of UB happen upon conversion.

Comment: Btw I also think Power ISA will trap in some cases, because the MMU monitors data memory vs instruction memory and you aren't allowed to execute code in data memory or do data access of instruction memory.

Comment: Why not instead return a valid pointer to a sentinel object, and then in the caller test for pointer equality with that? It's the same as your code, except valid C. However, this will still be somewhat error-prone since the user actively needs to check whether the returned object is an error sentinel or a valid object.

Comment: @Lundin So, that definitively rules out the first version (the cast of 1 to a pointer). Not because it is not legit. But because it may be turned into 0, for example (that is what I understand by "result is implementation defined": the result pointer may not be what one think it is. Which I would not care (since I am not really interested in the value), except that I cannot be sure that ONE is not the same as NULL.

Comment: @Lundin. I've harder time to believe that their could be a segment problem. I mean all machines that I know of (in 2022) have such segment protection, including my PC. And my PC does not complain about this. Segmentation problems should occur only when dereferencing. Otherwise, again, what of uninitialized pointer variables? They also hold impossible values. What of iterations with pointers, as the one in my previous comment (unlikely to be in another segment, but still points to nothing). It can't be illegal to have a pointer pointing to nothing legit. As long as you don't dereference it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph. Well, that 's, sort of, my second idea, at the end of my answer. Only, I don't allocate whole structure, because I don't think I really need to.

Comment: @chrslg Implementation-defined means exactly what I already explained - on some systems this might be fine, on others it might crash. It has nothing to do with null pointers. On an exotic system where the representation of a null pointer is non-zero, you wouldn't be able to create a null pointer by casting an integer constant other than zero to a pointer.

Comment: @chrslg Segmentation fault refers to data access out of bounds, so it's not exactly the same thing... "what of uninitialized pointer variables" They have indeterminate values, meaning just using one without de-referencing could invoke a trap. "As long as you don't dereference it" No, as long as you don't _use_ it. There are also various other UB rules not related to pointers where simply using an uninitialized local variable without taking its address invokes UB (since it could have been allocated in a register).

Comment: @chrslg That code is still invalid since it is violating aliasing rules. There's no need for any strange optimisations here. You have  a constant, completely negligible overhead by allocating a fixed number of objects *once*. You don't even need to (nor should) use `malloc`: point to statically allocated objects instead.